# Zend_config inject string

Tags: php, zend-framework

Take in example the following config:

```
array(
    'key' => 'value',
    'key2' => array(
        'key' => '@@INJECT@@',
        'key2' => 'value'
    ),
    'key3' => '@@INJECT@@'
);
```

Then this `array` is converted to `Zend_Config` object

But I try to find a way to replace `@@INJECT@@` with a specific value after converting Zend_Config object.

With a basic `array`, I use `array_walk_recursive()` to perform this task, but I do not find for `Zend_Config` object (and I don't want to convert `Zend_Config` object to `array`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could roll your own recursive walker, something like this:

```
function configWalkRecursive(Zend_Config $config, $callback)
{
    foreach ($config as $key => $item) {
        if ($item instanceof Zend_Config) {
            // recurse into child Zend_Config objects
            configWalkRecursive($item, $callback);
        } else {
            // run the callback against the element
            $callback($key, $item, $config);
        }
    }
}
```

This iterates over the elements in the Zend_Config, recurses if it finds another Zend_Config, otherwise passes the current item to a callback function.

Then, for your callback you could do something like this to test the items and replace as necessary:

```
$array = array(
    'key' => 'value',
    'key2' => array(
        'key' => '@@INJECT@@',
        'key2' => 'value'
    ),
    'key3' => '@@INJECT@@'
);

$config = new Zend_Config($array, true);

print_r($config);

configWalkRecursive($config, function($key, $item, $configObject) {
    if ('@@INJECT@@' === $item) {
        $configObject->$key = 'somevalue';
    }
);

print_r($config);
```

The output looks like this:

```
Zend_Config Object
(
    [_allowModifications:protected] => 1
    [_index:protected] => 0
    [_count:protected] => 3
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [key] => value
            [key2] => Zend_Config Object
                (
                    [_allowModifications:protected] => 1
                    [_index:protected] => 0
                    [_count:protected] => 2
                    [_data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => @@INJECT@@
                            [key2] => value
                        )

                    [_skipNextIteration:protected] => 
                    [_loadedSection:protected] => 
                    [_extends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_loadFileErrorStr:protected] => 
                )

            [key3] => @@INJECT@@
        )

    [_skipNextIteration:protected] => 
    [_loadedSection:protected] => 
    [_extends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_loadFileErrorStr:protected] => 
)
Zend_Config Object
(
    [_allowModifications:protected] => 1
    [_index:protected] => 3
    [_count:protected] => 3
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [key] => value
            [key2] => Zend_Config Object
                (
                    [_allowModifications:protected] => 1
                    [_index:protected] => 2
                    [_count:protected] => 2
                    [_data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => somevalue
                            [key2] => value
                        )

                    [_skipNextIteration:protected] => 
                    [_loadedSection:protected] => 
                    [_extends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_loadFileErrorStr:protected] => 
                )

            [key3] => somevalue
        )

    [_skipNextIteration:protected] => 
    [_loadedSection:protected] => 
    [_extends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_loadFileErrorStr:protected] => 
)
```